# How to handle request.GET with multiple variables for the same parameter in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

In a Django view you can access the `request.GET['variablename']`, so in your view you can do something like this:

```
myvar = request.GET['myvar']
```

The actual `request.GET['myvar']` object type is:

```
<class 'django.http.QueryDict'>
```

Now, if you want to pass multiple variables with the same parameter name, i.e:

`http://example.com/blah/?myvar=123&myvar=567`

You would like a python `list` returned for the parameter `myvar`, then do something like this:

```
for var in request.GET['myvar']:
    print(var)
```

However, when you try that you only get the last value passed in the url i.e in the example above you will get **567**, and the result in the shell will be:

```
5
6
7
```

However, when you do a print of `request.GET` it seems like it has a `list` i.e:

```
<QueryDict: {u'myvar': [u'123', u'567']}>
```

---

Ok Update:
It's designed to return the last value, my use case is i need a list.

from django docs:

> QueryDict.**getitem**(key) 
>   Returns
>   the value for the given key. If the
>   key has more than one value,
>   **getitem**() returns the last value. Raises
>   django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError
>   if the key does not exist. (This is a
>   subclass of Python's standard
>   KeyError, so you can stick to catching
>   KeyError
>
> QueryDict.getlist(key) Returns the
>   data with the requested key, as a
>   Python list. Returns an empty list if
>   the key doesn't exist. It's guaranteed
>   to return a list of some sort.

Update: 
If anyone knows why django dev's have done this please let me know, seems counter-intuitive to show a list and it does not behave like one. Not very pythonic!

Comment: I think the reasoning is that you should know whether to expect a list or individual value. QueryDict.getitem should not return a list sometimes, an individual item other times - then everyone would always have to check its return type in order to handle it properly.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

You want the [getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) function of the GET object:

```
request.GET.getlist('myvar')
```

Comment: You may need to add a "[]" to the end of the var name if you are using jquery to post items back.

Comment: I knew about getlist but the "[]" threw me. Also, I have a friend named Andy Staple, and for a second I thought he knew way the heck more about Django than I realized. That threw me as well.

Comment: This needs to be postered all over the Django docs, the Django Rest Framework docs, and backwards on my forehead. This really caught me off guard

Comment: It seems like Django kind of dropped the ball on that one, not sure if intended

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is creating a copy of the request object... Normally, you can not iterate through a request.GET or request.POST object, but you can do such operations on the copy:

```
res_set = request.GET.copy()
for item in res_set['myvar']:
    item
...
```

Comment: are you sure? this does not change the behavior of the QueryDict at all for me. i just get another QueryDict with the same "limitation"

Answer (score 1):

When creating a query string from a QueryDict object that contains multiple values for the same parameter (such as a set of checkboxes) use the urlencode() method:

For example, I needed to obtain the incoming query request, remove a parameter and return the updated query string to the resulting page.

```
# Obtain a mutable copy of the original string
original_query = request.GET.copy()

# remove an undesired parameter
if 'page' in original_query:
    del original_query['page']
```

Now if the original query has multiple values for the same parameter like this:
{...'track_id': ['1', '2'],...} you will lose the first element in the query string when using code like:

```
new_query = urllib.parse.urlencode(original_query)
```

results in...

```
...&track_id=2&...
```

However, one can use the urlencode method of the QueryDict class in order to properly include multiple values:

```
new_query = original_query.urlencode()
```

which produces...

```
...&track_id=1&track_id=2&...
```