# Django: How does view get multiple values from url?

Tags: python, django

It's about passing values from URL to view in django.

URL like this:
http:///boards/?**board**=picture&**board**=girls

I want get both values "picture" and "girls" that all belongs to **board**.
Store these values to a list or something.

Obviously, request.GET.get('board') can't get two values.

Does anybody get a workaround?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: maybe this question helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/problem-with-django-request-get-and-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-na

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`It's request.GET.getlist('board')` - it's stated in the Django docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Comment: @Jon Is there a documentation that says its OK to use multiple arguments in GET request with same name? (e.g. `board` in the above question has 2 values, is that a request that conforms to specs?)