# How to get multiple choices from template in views.py

Tags: django, django-views

In my template i have a multiple-choice-object like this:

```
<form action="/hmi/give_trend3/" method="get">
    <p>
        <select name="n" size="3" multiple="multiple">
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <option>{{ tag.name }}</option><br>
        {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

and i want to get all the values (of the multiple-choice) in my
views.py:

```
def give_trend3(request):
    v = request.GET['v']
    b = request.GET['b']
    nn = request.GET['n'] ....
```

but in the value `nn` I find only the last value of the choices.

How do I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Django request.GET and multiple variables for the same parameter name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/handling-django-request-get-and-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-name)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
vals = request.GET.getlist("n", '')
```

Also bind the id to the options in your template,

```
<select name="n" size="3" multiple="multiple">
{% for tag in tags %}
    <option value="{{ tag.id }}">{{ tag.name }}</option><br>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```