# Django request GET parameter value list

Tags: python, django

I want to do some sorting and what I have mind is doing a GET request with a parameter named ordering like this and the value will be the model atttribute that I will use to sort like this:

```
?order=['-age', 'height']
```

the problem is when I try to receive the order parameter.. The value is a list.

I tried using the ast like this:

```
if 'order' in request.GET:
        import ast
        order = ast.literal_eval(request.GET.get('order'))
        queryset = queryset.order_by(*order)
```

It worked. However, I would like to avoid using the ast library, is there any other way around?

**UPDATE**

I did my parameter like this:

?order=-age,height

And just used split in python like this:

```
if 'order' in request.GET:
    order = request.GET.get('order').split(',')
    queryset = queryset.order_by(*order)
```

Comment: Do you mean `.GET.getlist`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Django request.GET and multiple variables for the same parameter name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/handling-django-request-get-and-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-name)

Comment: @Sayse, This is the output when I use getlist.. [u'[-bet_amount,settlement_amount[']

Comment: The syntax you're using for your query parameters are incorect - `?order=-age&order=height`

Comment: @Sayse, I have an update on the question.. Please check if it is a good idea

Comment: Thats a bit of an opinion based question, it is a way of doing it, just like the multiple query parameters approach is also

Comment: @Sayse, so you think ?order=-age&order=height, is better?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django allows for multiple GET parameters to be sent in a request, but the way you're sending them is wrong (and not only for Django)
You request should be in the form `?order=-age&order=height`
Then in the view you can do `order_list = request.GET.getlist('order')`

You don't need to check if the key 'order' is in the GET parameters as `.getlist()` returns an empty list if the key is not found...

If you want only the first item from the list, you could use `request.GET.get('order')` which returns None if the key is not present.

Final code:

```
order_list = request.GET.getlist('order')
queryset = queryset.order_by(*order_list)
```

**P.S** While django allows GET parameters to be named anything, PHP (and I think other web languages) require GET lists parameters to be named as param[] (example order[]) and therefore libraries like JQuery name your AJAX request params as such. 
In this case you will have to use the correct name in your view i.e `request.GET.getlist('order[]')`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Very much appreciated it!