# Getting fullcalendar javascript click data to django modelform

Tags: javascript, python, django, fullcalendar

i want to click event on Fullcalendar, then it open another page, like this

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            dateClick: function(info) {
                window.open("{% url 'create-book' %}","_self");
            },
```

.
but how to get data from fullcalendar ?
there are function dateStr for show date, and resource.id, to show resource in timeline view(fullcalendar)

```
 alert('clicked ' + info.dateStr + ' on resource ' + info.resource.id);
```

.
what i want is bring dateStr and resource.id clicked data to django modelform,

here views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_book(request):
    booking_forms = BookingForm(initial={
        'resourceId':'xxxx',
        'startdate':'xxxx'
    })
```

im not sure what should i put on xxxx to get this through url on other page..

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any web application, if you want to pass data to another page, you generally add it to the URL in some way.

e.g. something like `/create_book?resourceId=123&startdate=2021-02-18`.

So in your case I'd expect something like

```
window.open("{% url 'create-book' %}?resourceId=" + encodeURIComponent(info.resource.id) + "&startdate=" + encodeURIComponent(info.dateStr),"_self");
```

would be needed on the client-side, and

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_book(request):
    booking_forms = BookingForm(initial={
        'resourceId': request.GET.get('resourceId'),
        'startdate': request.GET.get('startdate')
    })
```

on the server side.

Try it and let me know. (I'm not a django or python user, so the server-side code I'm not 100% about, but from reading [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823399/django-request-get-parameter-value-list) I think I've got the idea.)