# I want to make two queryset search in Django

Tags: django, filter, django-q

Using django.Filter() to search or filter the details of posts already saved in django.

Using Q of django to make search in queryset.
using checkbox, so that this filter(), to add a filter in my webpage
when --

> /?q=Bangalore

Im getting correct value as

```
LOCATION  BANGALORE  PUNE 
ujjwal
56789
hgjk@hgjhk.vds
bottle
bisleri
bangalore
Sept. 20, 2018, 3 p.m.
```

but when I am selecting both of the checkbox and perform search:

> ?q=Bangalore&q=Pune

if you notice the above url , it is performing '&' (and) opertion and, rather i want to show in search, the data of either of the value. Suppose, in database only, Bangalore is saved but not pune or vice-versa. It is showing nothing . ..

my code:

```
if query:
   queryset = queryset.filter(
   Q(Name__icontains = query) |      
   Q(Location__icontains= query) )
```

Hope I am able to make you understand my situation..

Comment: Tried `getlist`? request.GET.getlist('q')

Comment: no... thanx for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do something such as this:

```
from functools import reduce

query = request.GET.getlist('q')

queryset = queryset.filter(
    reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,
           [Q(Name__icontains=q) | Q(Location__icontains=q) for q in query]
    )
)
```

That will build up a `Q` object, `or`-ing each search term together.

Answer (score 0):

as the [Django Document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.lists) says, you can use this code to access a list of query_params witch have same key:

```
>>> q = QueryDict('a=1&a=2&a=3')
>>> q.lists()
[('a', ['1', '2', '3'])]
```

also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/handling-django-request-get-and-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-name) answer too.