# How do I send column values that I received with Request.Get.get consecutively?

Tags: python, django

I do order by with `request.GET.get('order_by',None)`

but

Now I want to trade with more columns.

Ex: `https://www.example.com/?order_by=col1&order_by=-col2`

and I want to get values.

```
columns = request.GET.getlist('order_by')
```

Then,

```
References.objects.order_by(*columns)
```

How do I create the above URL?

I tried to add the values I received with `Request.GET.get` to the list, but it was unreasonable. Because the same columns were added again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling Django request.GET and multiple variables for the same parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910165/handling-django-request-get-and-multiple-variables-for-the-same-parameter-name)

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is here.

Comment: I know this getlist but I just dont know get url.

Comment: I don't think you need to configure a url for accessing the get parameters. For detailed usage of urlconf and get parameters in url, you can refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get

Comment: Well then I ask how I can do multiple order_by. When I click first column is sorted. Then same thing for second column. Changes should not be lost. It should be ordered in both columns.